# web api bearer token authentication prompting for ntlm

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have a asp.net web api setup with oauth bearer tokens, it works great with my angular app, but when I make an unauthorized request it sends a 401 and the browser prompts for basic or NTLM credentials before I can intercept it. I don't want that. Looking at the response headers I'm getting 3 www-authenticate's

WWW-Authenticate    Bearer
WWW-Authenticate    Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate    NTLM

I'm guessing the browser (IE11) gives me the prompt due to the last two, but how can I remove this? I have the authenication mode set to none, and config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication(); set in my webapiconfig, what am I missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you go to your site using IIS Manager and look into the Authentication options of it, is Windows Auth enabled?

Comment: This is just running on iis express but I think I did enable that, ill try turning it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negotiate and NTLM are the default providers for Windows Authentication. You have probably enabled it by mistake on the Authentication options of your IIS site, or in Visual Studio in the properties of your site for IIS Express:

[image]